# Location Setting for ACF field to template part that used in search.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to wordpress theme developments. I used ACF fields in my wordpress template. But acf fields value aren't showed if it is **not connected to page** in admin dashboard.Like search.php file where wordpress redirect search to this page. At search.php, I used a template part called cta.php. It works fine with various page template say service template. 
If the url becomes **wordpress/post_type="post"&s="battery"** then the results appear at search.php where cta.php template part also used. So, **how can I set location rule for fields of cta** to appear at search.php?

Answer (score 1):

There is no interface to edit the search results page, so an [ACF option page](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/) will need to be created/used and that location also set for the field group. The `cta.php` template part will then need to check if `is_search()` is `true` and change where it retrieves ACF data from (untested):

`cta.php`:

```php
$acf_post_id = get_queried_object_id();

if ( is_search() ) {
    $acf_post_id = 'option';
}

the_field( 'cta_title', $acf_post_id );
```

Or, if you need to be more explicit:

```php
$title = get_field( 'cta_title' );

if ( is_search() ) {
    $title = get_field( 'default_cta_title', 'option' );
}

echo $title;
```

Comment: Thanks. But after a while I found a workaround to solve it indirectly. As, I used the template part at Home page, I can then retrieve the value of those field by using Home page id.
```$home = get_page_by_path("Home"); $id = $home->ID;```
Now, ```the_field('cta_title', $id)``` gives me the value. And I can use a single location rule there and it will be changed everywhere the template part used.

Answer (score 1):

After a while I found a workaround to solve it indirectly. As, I used the template part at Home page, I can then retrieve the value of those field by using Home page id. `$home = get_page_by_path("Home"); $id = $home->ID;` Now, `the_field('cta_title', $id)` gives me the value. And I can use a single location rule over there and it will be changed everywhere the template part used.

```html
<div class="cta-area">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row cta-content">
            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-12 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".2s">
            <?php $home = get_page_by_path('Home');
                if($home): ?>
                <h2><?php the_field('cta_title', $home->ID); ?></h2>
                <p><?php the_field('cta_intro', $home->ID); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-12 text-center wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".3s">
                <a href="<?php $call = get_page_by_path('Call'); echo $call ? get_permalink($call->ID): '#';?>" class="main-btn">Get a Call</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```